# Show that $G$ is a Groebner bases of $I$ if division of $f$ on $G$ is zero for all $f\in I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, groebner-basis

> Let $I=\langle g_1,\dots, g_t\rangle$ be an ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $k$ a field. Let $G=\{g_1,\dots,g_t\}$. Show that if the remainder of $f$ on division by $G$ is $0$ for all $f\in I$, then $G$ is a Groebner basis.

My attempt:

We need to show that $\text{LT}(f)$ is divisible by $\text{LT}(g_i)$ for some $g_i\in G$, for all $f\in I$, where $\text{LT}(\cdot)$ means the leading term of the polynomial.

Since $f\in I$, and $G$ is a bases of $I$, we can write 
$$f=\sum_{i=0}^t h_i g_i$$ 
for some $h_i\in k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$. I don't know how to continue then, since I cannot write the leading term of $f$ in terms of a single $g_i$. It can be combination of $g_i$'s. So I cannot say it is divisible by one of them.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint: Use contradiction.  Assume $f\in I$, but no leading term of a $g_i$ divides the leading term of $f$.  Then, what is the remainder?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I see. The remainder then contains the leading term of $f$. Thanks!

Comment: @user26857: It is from the book of Cox, etc. again. The definition of a Groebner basis in that book is that a subset $G$ is a Groebner basis if $\left\langle LT(g_1),...,LT(g_t)\right\rangle =\left\langle LT(I)\right\rangle$.

Comment: You start with a system of generators for $I$, declare them a Grobner basis for $I$, and in the end you want to show that under some condition they form a Grobner basis!!!

Comment: @user26857: No I didn't declare them a Groebner basis. It is just a basis. And I am showing that they are Groebner. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take ${\rm LT}$ in $$f=\sum_{i=0}^t h_i g_i.$$ Then ${\rm LT}(f)=\sum_j{\rm LT}(h_j){\rm LT}(g_j)\in\langle{\rm LT}(g_1),\dots,{\rm LT}(g_t)\rangle$.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that ${\rm LT}(f)$ is not necessarily ${\rm LT}(h_jg_j)$ for some $j$, but it is certainly a sum of such leading terms (whenever some of them are equal). (We know, although not very clearly stated in Cox and al. that ${\rm LT}(f)\ge{\rm LT}(h_ig_i)$ for all $i$. This is a natural condition we impose when perform a long division. There is no reason to leave such leading terms to be greater then those of $f$ and then reduce them.)

Comment: Yes, we could prove it that way too.