# Doubt in computation of groebner basis and proving a set is a groebner basis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

I have a set $G$ , and I am trying to prove that the set is a groebner basis .

From chapter $2$ of Ideals,Varieties and Algorithm I have the following theorem,

> A basis $G = \{g_1,\cdots, g_n \}$ for an ideal I is a Gröbner basis if and only if $S(g_i, g_j) \to_{G}  0 $ for all $i \ne j$.

My ideal $I$ is generated by $y_1+ y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2$,$y_1+ y_2*x_2 + y_3*x_2^2$,$y_1 + y_2*x_1+y_2*x_1^2$ and the monomial order is $(y_1>y_2>y_3>x_1>x_2>x_3)$ lexicographic ordering

The set  $G$ is $\{y_3*x_1^2*x_2 - y_3*x_1^2*x_3 - y_3*x_1*x_2^2 + y_3*x_1*x_3^2 + y_3*x_2^2*x_3 - y_3*x_2*x_3^2 , y_2*x_2 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_2^2 - y_3*x_3^2 , y_2*x_1 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_1^2 - y_3*x_3^2 , y_1+ y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2\}$

I am trying to claim is that this set $G$ is the groebner basis of $I$

I calculated the $6$, S-polynomials of the polynomials in $G$ and I have shown that the remainder obtained after dividing these (by the polynomials present in G) is $0$ .

Is this process enough to conclude that $G$ is a groebner basis of $I$?

Or should I be calculating the leading term of $S(g_i,g_j)$ where $i \ne j$ and $g_i,g_j \in G$ and then checking whether the leading term of this $S$-polynomial  is present in the ideal generated by $\langle LT(g_1),Lt(g_2) ,\cdots Lt(g_n) \rangle$?

Edit 1:I have done the calculations and I wanted someone to check the way that I have **written and done ** the proof is correct or not.

A basis $G = \{g_1 \cdots g_n\}$ for an ideal $I$ is a Gröbner basis if and only if $S(g_i, g_j) \to_{G} 0$ for all $i \ne j$.

$I = \langle y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2,y_1+y_2*x_2+y_3*x_2^2,y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2 \rangle $

Then the set $G$ is a basis if $y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2 (mod G) = 0$,$,y_1+y_2*x_2+y_3*x_2^2 (mod G) = 0$, $y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2 (mod G) = 0 $

**We try to prove that after using the multivaraite divison algorithm $y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2$ (mod G) $= 0$ **

Dividing  $y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2$ by $y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2$ we get the remainder as $y_2*x_1 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_1^2 - y_3*x_3^2  $

Then, dividing $y_2*x_1 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_1^2 - y_3*x_3^2  $ by $y_2*x_3 - y_2*x_1 + y_3*x_3^2 - y_3*x_1^2 $ we get the remiander as $0$ and the quotient as $-1$

Then, $y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2=1.(y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2)+-1.(y_2*x_3 - y_2*x_1 + y_3*x_3^2 - y_3*x_1^2 )$

So the remainder obtained is $0$ after dividing it by $G$

We try to prove that after using the multivaraite divison algorithm $y_1+y_2*x_2+y_3*x_2^2$ (mod G) $= 0$

Dividing  $y_1+y_2*x_2+y_3*x_2^2$ by $y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2$ we get the remainder as $y_2*x_1 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_1^2 - y_3*x_3^2  $

Then, dividing $-y_2*x_2 + y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_2^2 + y_3*x_3^2  $ by $y_2*x_3 - y_2*x_1 + y_3*x_3^2 - y_3*x_1^2 $ we get the remainder as $0$ and the quotient as $-1$

Then, $y_1+y_2*x_1+y_3*x_1^2=1.(y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2)+-1.((-y_2*x_2 + y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_2^2 + y_3*x_3^2 )$

So the remainder obtained is $0$ after dividing it by $G$

We try to prove that after using the multivaraite divison algorithm $y_1+y_2*x_3+y_3*x_3^2$ (mod G) $= 0$

It is easy to see because the polynomial is itself present in the set $G$.

So we conclude from here that **$G$ is a basis**

**We try to prove that $G$ is a Gröbner basis by showing that $S(g_i, g_j) \to_{G} 0$ for all $i \ne j$**

i)S($ y_2*x_3 - y_2*x_1 + y_3*x_3^2 - y_3*x_1^2 ,y_1+ y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2$)=$y_1*y_2*x_3 - y_1*y_3*x_1^2 + y_1*y_3*x_3^2 + y_2^2*x_1*x_3 + y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2$

We try to show that this $S$-polynomial obtained gives a zero remainder after division by $G$.

1.dividing by $(y_1 + y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2)$

a)substract: $(y_1 + y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2)(y_2*x_3)$ from  becomes $-y_1*y_3*x_1^2 + y_1*y_3*x_3^2 + y_2^2*x_1*x_3 - y_2^2*x_3^2 + y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2 - y_2*y_3*x_3^3 $

b)subtract $(y_1 + y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2)(-y_3*x_1^2)$ from f becomes
$y_1*y_3*x_3^2 + y_2^2*x_1*x_3 - y_2^2*x_3^2 + y_2*y_3*x_1^2*x_3 + y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2 - y_2*y_3*x_3^3 + y_3^2*x_1^2*x_3^2$

c)substract $(y_1 + y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2)(y_3*x_3^2)$ from f becomes $y_2^2*x_1*x_3 - y_2^2*x_3^2 + y_2*y_3*x_1^2*x_3 + y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2 - 2*y_2*y_3*x_3^3 + y_3^2*x_1^2*x_3^2 - y_3^2*x_3^4$

2.dividing $(-y_2*x_1 + y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_1^2 + y_3*x_3^2)$

a)substract $(-y_2*x_1 + y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_1^2 + y_3*x_3^2)(-y_2*x_3)$ from f becomes $y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2 - y_2*y_3*x_3^3 + y_3^2*x_1^2*x_3^2 - y_3^2*x_3^4$

b)substract$ (-y_2*x_1 + y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_1^2 + y_3*x_3^2)(-y_3*x_3^2)$ from  f becomes $0$.

$y_1*y_2*x_3 - y_1*y_3*x_1^2 + y_1*y_3*x_3^2 + y_2^2*x_1*x_3 + y_2*y_3*x_1*x_3^2$=$0*y_3*x_1^2*x_2 - y_3*x_1^2*x_3 - y_3*x_1*x_2^2 + y_3*x_1*x_3^2 + y_3*x_2^2*x_3 - y_3*x_2*x_3^2 + 0*y_2*x_2 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_2^2 - y_3*x_3^2 + (y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2)*y_2*x_1 - y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_1^2 - y_3*x_3^2 + (y_2*x_3 - y_3*x_1^2 + y_3*x_3^2)*y_1+ y_2*x_3 + y_3*x_3^2 $

I have adopted the similar process for the rest of the $S$-polynomial to get a zero remainder after division by the polynomials in the set $G$.

I need someone to look into my proof and also for the way I have written it.

Comment: It seems almost right. I also have four polynomials, but the first one is a bit different, namely $y_3x_1^2x_2^2 - y_3x_1^2x_3^2 + y_3x_1x_2^2 - y_3x_1x_3^2 - y_3x_2^2x_3 + y_3x_2x_3^2$.

Comment: Maybe,I made a mistake while computing.I just wanted to ask which method should I use to conclude that $G$ (say if I have a set G from the beginning) is a groebner basis of I?

Comment: I think my question is not clear - my doubt is if I have a set $G$ (already given to me) how do I show that it is a groebner basis

Comment: A set $G$ is a Groebner basis for $I$, if for all polynomials $f$ we have $f\in I$ if and only if  $f$ has remainder zero with the multivariate division by $G$, i.e., iff $f \bmod G=0$.

Comment: However how do we conclude that it generates the set $I$?

Comment: So, what does the theorem in Cox try to mean ? It is there in chapter 2 -section 9 ,theorem 3.This is the buchberger's criterion that $S(g_i,g_j)$ has to be $0$ after division by $G$ but then do we have to show that the generators of the ideal $I$ mod $G$ also gives 0 to prove $G$ is a grobner basis?

Comment: @DietrichBurde isn't the definition given by you  satisfied by all the generators of the ideal?

Comment: No, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282406/show-that-g-is-a-groebner-bases-of-i-if-division-of-f-on-g-is-zero-for-a) for what I mean.